# Export Tab's as individual reports

Tags: powerbi, export-to-pdf

I have a power BI file with 64 tabs/pages when I export to PDF I get just one big PDF how can I export each tab/page as its down PDF file?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to this? I have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that PowerBI's Export to PDF function has no configuration to do this directly from PowerBI.

However, PDF specific utilities have one-step processes to divide your 64 page document into 64 PDF files.  In Nuance PDF, select Advanced Processing >> Split. Choose "Split by pages:" and set the value to 1.  I expect other PDF utilities have similar functionality.